# Why do some LED bulbs stay on when my dimmer is off?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, led

The front room of our rented house has 8 down-lighter spotlights on one of those dimmers that you use a silver disc to turn on and off and supposedly dim. Beside the switch is another separate dimmer Switch, same type, that powers two dimmable other wall lights.

Since being in, the lights seem to have their own mind, and on occasion, the main 8 will turn themselves fully on, then dim, then go off. We noticed that all the bulbs were 50w halogen. Even the TV remote with at times turn them all on.

We changed all bulbs for 5w led bulbs. Now, we can turn them on, but turning off, a different bulb will stay on. Changes bulb each time we turn on or off. The bulbs are dimmable.

Checked wiring and have attached how the two dimmers are wired. Any ideas please?
House built in 80s. Oh, and the lights in question also have a remote (for varilight?) which seems to do bugger all.

[image: wiring of the two dimmer switches]

Comment: Welcome. Please [edit] that into some readable paragraphs - that will make it much easier to parse the info from the background from the question. With your reduced rent, did the landlord give you _written_ permission to do whatever repairs were necessary, and indemnification from any work that may go wrong?

Comment: The issue is whether or not you are *legally* allowed to do any electrical work on the house. In many places, **resident homeowners** can do moderate levels of electrical work on their house, but landlords and tenants can't. Your landlord has given you permission, but there *may* be legal issues if you make any changes and later on there is a fire. That being said, the simplest thing to do is generally to replace with simple (not smart, not dimmer, not motion, not timer) switches. If those switches solve the problem then you can work towards figuring out to add back dimming. Simple switches

Comment: are so inexpensive that even if they get thrown away after a day to replace with something better, you haven't lost much.

Comment: I removed a bunch of the non-essential chatter from the question. [We're not a discussion forum](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour), and that's not appropriate unless it informs answers.

Comment: that dimmer looks slightly burned (discolored), i would replace it with an LED compatible one that can better handle capacitive loads.